# Pandas "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Timedelta' and 'float'"

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, plot

I'm trying to use pandas autocorrelation_plot() function with a sql result filled data frame but i keep getting this error when i run this code:

```
import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas.tools.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host = "host", user = "user", passwd = "passwd", db = "db")
exect = connection.cursor()
query = "query"
exect.execute(query)
frame = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
connection.close()
print(frame.head())
autocorrelation_plot(frame)
pyplot.show()
```

i can print the frame without a problem, but when i try to use the autocorrelation_plot() function i get this error. The output of my data frame is this:

```
time      value
0 00:00:14  283.80
1 00:01:14  271.97
2 00:02:14  320.53
3 00:03:14  346.78
4 00:04:14  280.72
5 00:05:14  277.41
6 00:06:14  308.65
7 00:07:14  321.27
8 00:08:14  320.68
9 00:09:14  332.32
```

Comment: Do you know what you are trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to plot the auto-correlation from a time-series that looks like this when i print the value of frame: 
0 00:00:14  283.80
1 00:01:14  271.97
2 00:02:14  320.53
3 00:03:14  346.78
4 00:04:14  280.72

Comment: Print `df.head(10)` and post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might benefit from using `set_index` to set `time` as the index before plotting.

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

df    
      time   value
0 00:00:14  283.80
1 00:01:14  271.97
2 00:02:14  320.53
3 00:03:14  346.78
4 00:04:14  280.72
5 00:05:14  277.41
6 00:06:14  308.65
7 00:07:14  321.27
8 00:08:14  320.68
9 00:09:14  332.32

df.dtypes     
time     timedelta64[ns]
value            float64
dtype: object

autocorrelation_plot(df.set_index('time'))
plt.show()
```

[image]